# Llenar combobox y auto completar inputs con php

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero saber cómo puedo hacer el llenado de un combobox con php, ya que quiero que dependiendo de lo seleccionado en el combobox se llenen automáticamente los inputs

Tengo una tabla llamada operadores

```
id nombre   numero
1  carlos   1
2  gregorio 2
```

En mi html quiero que en un combobox se seleccione el nombre y dependiendo del nombre, que un input de tipo texto se asigne el número.

Comment: Por que la etiqueta javascript?

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores por que se que tambien se puede con llavascript

Comment: Exacto pero tu pregunta esta mal formulada, pues lo arias con ajax desde javascript, si sabes utilizar dime y te pongo un ejemplo como seria con JS

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores aun estoy aprendiendo a usar ajax y javascript, en mi proyecto lo estoy usando, ya que uso los DataTables

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores pero de verdad agradeceria tu ayuda infinitamente

Answer (score 0):

Partiré desde el punto en que asumo que estás escuchando el evento de cambio para el combo de los nombres y dado que no adjuntaste código, crearé uno breve e imaginario:

```
$('#comboNombres').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"ruta.php?nombre="+$(this).val(),
        success: function(response){
            $('#inputNumeros').val(response)
        }
    });
});
```

El response, debería idealmente consultar y retornar el valor que vas a poner en el input.

Comment: De hecho no tengo nada jeje he estado leyendo un poco acerca de como se deberia hacer, y de igual manera he leido que con js es mas dificil llenar un combo y tomar el valor del seleccionado